# antlr error message seems self-contradictory? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

I have the following antlr4 grammar in file xbf.g4

```
grammar xbf;

prog: ( struct_def )* ;

type:  ( type_uint | type_float | type_string ) ;

type_uint: U8 | U16 | U32 | U64 ;
type_float: F32 | F64 ;
type_string: '"' STRLIT? '"' ;

struct_def: STRUCT IDENT '{' ( member )* '}' ;
member: IDENT ':' type ',' ;

STRUCT: 'struct' ;
IDENT: [a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-ΩА-Яа-я][a-zA-Z0-9_α-ωΑ-ΩА-Яа-я]* ;

U8: 'u8' ;
U16: 'u16' ;
U32: 'u32' ;
U64: 'u64' ;

F32: 'f32' ;
F64: 'f64' ;

STRLIT: '"' (~[\r\n"] | '\\"')* '"' ;
WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip;
```

The program parses the following file:

```
struct vec3d {
  x : f32,
  y : f32,
  z : f32,
}
```

The error message is

```
line 2:6 mismatched input 'f32' expecting {'"', 'u8', 'u16', 'u32', 'u64', 'f32', 'f64'}
line 3:6 mismatched input 'f32' expecting {'"', 'u8', 'u16', 'u32', 'u64', 'f32', 'f64'}
line 4:6 mismatched input 'f32' expecting {'"', 'u8', 'u16', 'u32', 'u64', 'f32', 'f64'}
```

So it's expected one of the symbols including f32, it finds f32, but it's an error?

Comment: Your grammmar has useless parentheses. You should remove them. `( struct_def )*` -> `struct_def*`, `( type_uint | type_float | type_string )` -> `type_uint | type_float | type_string`, `( member )*` -> `member*`. Also, unless you know what you are doing, the start rule `prog : struct_def*;` should be EOF-terminated: `prog : struct_def* EOF;`. For example, it will accept `struct vec { x : f32, } xstruct as { dd : dsf, }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer creates tokens using the following 2 rules:

1. try to match as many characters as possible
2. when 2 (or more) rules match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Because of rule 2, the input `f32` is tokenized as a `IDENT` token, not as a `F32` token. The solution: move your `IDENT` rule below all `U...` and `F...` rules:

```
STRUCT: 'struct' ;

U8: 'u8' ;
U16: 'u16' ;
U32: 'u32' ;
U64: 'u64' ;

F32: 'f32' ;
F64: 'f64' ;

IDENT: [a-zA-Zα-ωΑ-ΩА-Яа-я][a-zA-Z0-9_α-ωΑ-ΩА-Яа-я]* ;
```